# Jquery ui show() method conflict with cookie in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, cookies

I have to maintain state of the sidebar in cookie. so what I have done just clik on the hide sidebar button i have created the cookie to maintain its state. look at following code.

```
//Create Cookie function which is usefull to create cookies

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
//Read Cookie function which is usefull to read cookies vlues
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
//Earse Cookie function which is usefull to earise cookies vlues
function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
// This function is used for  sidebar state managemnet operations.
function checksidebarstatus()
{
    var sidebarval = '';
    sidebarval = readCookie('sidebarval');
    if(sidebarval == 'hide')
    {   
        jQuery(".show-sidebar").fadeIn();
        jQuery("#main").css( "width","950" );
        jQuery("#sidebar").hide();
    }
}
```

Now when hidesidar button code to hidesidebar as follow

```
// Sidebar Animation
jQuery("#hide-sidebar").click(function(){

    if(sidebarval == "hide")
    {
        //jQuery("#sidebar").delay(500).hide("slow");
        jQuery("#sidebar").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    }else
    {
        jQuery("#sidebar").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    }
    jQuery("#main").delay(500).animate({
        width: 950
    }, 1000 );
    jQuery(".show-sidebar").delay(1500).fadeIn();
    createCookie('sidebarval','hide',7);
});

jQuery("#show-sidebar").click(function(){

    jQuery(".show-sidebar").fadeOut();
    jQuery("#main").animate({
        width: 760
    }, 500 );
    if(sidebarval == "hide")
    {    
        //jQuery("#sidebar").delay(500).show("slow");
        jQuery("#sidebar").delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    }else
    {
        jQuery("#sidebar").delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    }   
    createCookie('sidebarval','show',7);
});
```

Now the i have js varible to get cookie data id as follow

```
var sidebarval = readCookie('sidebarval');
```

Now as i the code it must have to run but when i get cookie value it will not allow this

```
jQuery("#sidebar").delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

If I uncomment this line then this show method works.

```
jQuery("#sidebar").delay(500).show("slow");
//jQuery("#sidebar").delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

Can anyone tell me how this is possible. 
Thanks.

Comment: can u paste u r code html and jquery code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) file in your project. The top show works for you because it's in the default JQuery library of code. The bottom show method, the one that doesn't work, is part of the JQuery UI Effects Core. You need to build yourself the JQuery UI file with this option included and it will work.

Here's a link to the show function there:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/

Comment: I don't understand. What does this mean? "it will only reside and display the main container and not sidebar". Could you set up a jsfiddle?